# How to use multiple datasources types with the same repositories?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I created a multi-tenant logic and I am storing the tenant number in `ThreadLocal`. Everything works very good when the databases are of the same type (dialects). During the spring boot initialization, the JPA repositories are initialized (its SQL queries) with the first (and default) datasource.

However when I have for example Oracle and Postgres database configured, spring boot still tries to make queries with the dialect of the first tenant datasource and that's quite big problem as dialects for the database types are different.

This creates dataSource of the tenant type. If tenant is not known yet (during startup) it will take the tenant-1.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    String tenant1 = "tenant-1";
    String tenant2 = "tenant-2";

    CustomRoutingDataSource customRoutingDataSource = new CustomRoutingDataSource();

    final DataSource tenant1DataSource = createDataSourceForTenant(tenant1);
    final DataSource tenant2DataSource = createDataSourceForTenant(tenant2);

    HashMap<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
    targetDataSources.put(tenant1.toUpperCase(), tenant1DataSource);
    targetDataSources.put(tenant2.toUpperCase(), tenant2DataSource);

    customRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    return customRoutingDataSource;
}
```

This will create the datasource statically - will be replaced by dynamical extraction from JNDI sources later, when I solve the problem:

```
private DataSource createDataSourceForTenant(String tenant) throws SQLException {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"entities"});

    if (tenant.equalsIgnoreCase("tenant-1")) {
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/importservices");
        dataSource.setUsername("test");
        dataSource.setPassword("test");

        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    if (tenant.equalsIgnoreCase("tenant-2")) {
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle11:1521/deviso");
        dataSource.setUsername("test");
        dataSource.setPassword("test");

        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    factoryBean.destroy();
    return dataSource;
}
```

Custom database routing. getTenant returns the default value (1) when tenant is not available (during startup).

```
public class CustomRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return "TENANT-"+TenantThreadLocal.getTenant();
    }

}
```

Now if I have default tenant = 1, spring boot initializes on startup and creates PostgreSQL-specific queries for entities. If I access it in runtime as tenant 2 (Oracle dialect), I am getting:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

as Spring JPA has initialized the JPA repositories with PostgreSQL dialect. So the possiblities are:

**1)** Multiple EntityManagers per tenant - not really comfortable, as tenants are dynamically managed
**2)** Multi-tenancy support in hibernate - actually I could not this get working, as jadira framework has some problems with multi-tenant support and before 2 weeks still was not fixed and waiting for [fix](https://github.com/JadiraOrg/jadira/issues/19) 
**3)** ??

Answer (score 0):

There are changes in the (just released) Jadira 5.0.0.GA to co-exist with multitenant deployments. Disclaimer: I maintain Jadira.